# Finding azimuth and zenith angles for tetrahedron

Tags: angle

I have an irregular tetrahedron as shown in figure below, and I know the length of all of its edges. I want to find the azimuth and zenith angles $\phi$, and $\theta$ for vector $C$.

I managed to find the zenith angle $\theta$ by finding the volume using Cayley-Menger Determinant and the equation volume = $(A\times B).C$; however I can't find the azimuth angle $\theta$.

Any help is appreciated to find azimuth angle $\phi$.

Best regards,

[image: attached image]

Answer (score 1):

Call $x$ the axis containing the edge $OA$, $z$ the axis wrt the polar angle $\theta$ is measured,  $y$ the remaining axis
and $\bf c$ the vector $OC$.
Knowing the edges, by the cosines rule you can determine the angle $AOC$.
So you have $c_z, c_x$ and can subsequently determine $c_y$ from the $\left\| {\bf c} \right\|$.

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant. however I can't determine  $c_y$ has a negative value!! Do have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: which are the three facet angles in O ?